# monodevelop asp.net xsp4 change default address/port?

Tags: 14.04, configuration, webserver, mono, monodevelop

How to explain to monodevelop asp.net app to run xsp[4] server from other port than default 8080?

Tried to change defaults in /etc/default/mono-xsp but that do not make difference to monodevelop runtime config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the root of the web application you can run `xsp4 --port YOURPORT`. Or fromo monodevelop, as you asked, you can set the web application as your startup project and go to "Project > yourprojectname Options > XSP Web Server" and set the port number.

[image: An image says more than a thousand words?]